# Can Vortex tubes be used in cooling rooms?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cooling, compressed-air

Vortex tubes have been used extensively to some extent in cooling small areas. However, can they be used to cool larger rooms. Through some research, I found out that an average vortex tube may take up to 40 hours to cool a normal-sized bedroom, which is inefficient and energy-intensive.

However, can we use the cold air coming from the vortex tube as medium where the hot air coming from the room exchange heat, creating the cooling effect. The hot inlet coming from the vortex tube can be utilized as waste heat or could be rejected to the outside.

I feel this design is trivial and may have some flaws. I would appreciate if someone would confirm if this would work and what flaws that it may contain.

Answer (score 2):

Can it?  Yes, but it's only practical if you have a cheap supply of compressed gas.  This is a niche application, and is nowhere close to the amount of heat you can move with traditional refrigeration systems, which use state change from gas to liquid and back to move heat with less power input than the heat moved.

So the question isn't "can it?" as much as "why should we?"